# Paperclip: Saving Blog Posts with Pictures doesn't work, without does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have follow the [paperclip tutorial](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) on their github page.

I've created a migration

```
rails g paperclip blog picture
```

in my blog.rb (model)

```
has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { :medium => "600x400>", :thumb => "260x180>" }
attr_accessible :title, :body, :picture
```

in my controller

```
def create
@blog = Blog.new( params[:blog] )
respond_to
```

and so on....

in my _form.html

```
<%= form_for @blog, :html => { :multipart => true, :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

now if I try to create a new Blog without an image, it gets created like usual. However, if I try to create one with an picture, it doesn't get created and I get redirected to the `new_blogs_path`. The redirecting is fine, considered I have a if `@blog.save respond_to`, so all that happens is that it doesn't seem to get saved.

anybody got an idea?

Comment: Does this happen on your box or in production as in Heroku?

Comment: box, development. didn't test it on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Please use whole command like this

```
        rails generate paperclip user avatar
```

Not

```
          rails g paperclip user avatar
```

Please check these coloumns exist in your db.

```
1 avatar_file_name 
2 avatar_content_type 
3 avatar_file_size 
4 avatar_updated_at
```

and then tell me.If not exist then create manually and i hope it will work....

Comment: well... i rolled back my database and created a new migration for you using rails generate paperclip blog picture. still doesn't work.

Comment: Please check these coloumns exist in your db. 1 avatar_file_name 2 avatar_content_type 3 avatar_file_size 4 avatar_updated_at and then tell me.If not exist then create manually and i hope it will work....